# Missing /lib/modules/4.14.44-t1-r51/build

Tags: drivers, wireless

I'm trying to compile the driver for wifi realtek RTL8188CUS, but make is ending with error `missing /lib/modules/4.14.44-t1-r51/build`.

WIFI adapter I am using is Edimax with the following result from lsusb

```
Edimax Technology Co., Ltd EW-7811Un 802.11n Wireless Adapter [Realtek RTL8188CUS]
```

Ubuntu 18.04 running on beaglebone Black

Somebody advise for me, please?

Comment: You are using an unofficial kernel; where is it from?

Comment: I doubt that you need to build a driver for this device? Is it working, perhaps poorly, now? Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: comming from next url:https://linuxpropaganda.wordpress.com/2018/06/26/install-ubuntu-server-on-beaglebone-black/         source:https://rcn-ee.com/rootfs/2018-06-08/flasher/